# Is there difference between using self.attribute and attribute in a model callbacks conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

is there any difference in callback adding conditions by using self.attribute_changed? or attribute_changed?

```
    class PlayEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
      ... 
      after_save :update_next_event_at!, if: 'self.event_at_changed?'
      after_save :update_next_event_at!, if: 'event_at_changed?'
      ...    

    end
```

which one is preferred to use?

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference, the `self.` isn't needed.

The only time you need `self.` is on assignment.  If you have a model attribute `comment` and a method like...

```
def update_comment
  comment = "this is the new comment"
end
```

It may not be what you're expecting, as the assignment in this case creates a variable `comment` which is local to the method.  Rubocop identifies this as a useless assignment as the `comment` variable is not subsequently used anywhere.

However...

```
def update_comment
  self.comment = "this is the new comment"
end
```

Will correctly change the record attribute.